# How can i make my array start a new line at the end or get it to wrap?

Tags: php

I want after the name Paula for it to either start a new line or wrap onto a new line where am i going wrong?

```
<?php
$array = array('Seb', 'Ginna', 'Shane', 'Guy', 'Jackie', 'Frances', 'John', 'Alec', 'Jon', 'Sam', 'Chris', 'Paula');
$Length = 120;
$newArray = array();
while(count($newArray) <= $Length){
$newArray = array_merge($newArray, $array);
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
echo $comma_separated;
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the logic? *"After Paula"*? Or *"after second to last"*? Or *"or before '/'"*?

Comment: Voting to close, it's hard to figure out what exactly is being asked.

Comment: so it would go to Paula then start from Seb on a new line

Comment: Your code is complicated. I might be out of context but you could do i only with a foreach. No new arrays and stuff.

Comment: @TCB13 How would i do it with foreach? As i need it to loop 10 times

Comment: @user1839483 can you elaborate a little bit in what is supposed to be functionality and output of your code?

Comment: @TCB13 i just want the list of names output 10 times. I am new to php and am trying to self learn (proving to be harder then i thought)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1839483 your problem is clearly the way you think... You should read something into how to create algorithms.

Still, I'm going to rewrite your code, even not being what I should do.

```
<?php
$theNames = array('Seb', 'Ginna', 'Shane', 'Guy', 'Jackie', 'Frances', 'John', 'Alec', 'Jon', 'Sam', 'Chris', 'Paula');

$toOutput = implode(",", $theNames);

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    print $toOutput."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you this is the information i needed where i should be looking for this information. I am self Learning which is not fun but will be worth while

Comment: Is there anyway i can contact you outside of here so that you could advise me what i should be looking up without giving me the answer?

Comment: @user1839483 I don't work for free. Contact info on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

It's `<br>` for HTML or `\n` for the text format (if the HTTP response is of type `text/plain` for example), not `/`.